# word macro to highlight sets of words in different colors

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a Word macro that I customized a while back from someone else's (unfortunately I can't find the source). The purpose is to highlight all occurrences of "he" and "his" in turquoise, and all the occurrences of "she" and "her" in pink. It works partially -- it does highlight "he" (but not "his") in turquoise, and "she" (but not "her") in pink.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub HighLightHeShe()
    Dim vFindText As Variant
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    vFindText = Array("he", "his")
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Do While .Execute(FindText:=vFindText(i), _
                          MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                          Forward:=True, _
                          Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
            oRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
            oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
    vFindText = Array("she", "her")
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Do While .Execute(FindText:=vFindText(i), _
                          MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                          Forward:=True, _
                          Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
            oRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
            oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are only finding the first item in each array is because you are not changing the value of "i". You need to wrap the "Finds" in a loop.

See below ...

```
Sub HighLightHeShe()
    Dim vFindText As Variant
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    vFindText = Array("he", "his")
    For i = 0 To UBound(vFindText)
        Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
        With oRng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            Do While .Execute(FindText:=vFindText(i), _
                              MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                              Forward:=True, _
                              Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
                oRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
                oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Loop
        End With
    Next

    vFindText = Array("she", "her")
    For i = 0 To UBound(vFindText)
        Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
        With oRng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            Do While .Execute(FindText:=vFindText(i), _
                              MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                              Forward:=True, _
                              Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
                oRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
                oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Loop
        End With
    Next

lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: @IzaO if you are doing this often on documents and have a variety of words and phrases to find and highlight, I recommend you do a web search on AuthorTec Find'n Highlight. It's a free add-in to Word.